# Cross browser window close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser, onunload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close /Kills the seesion when  close the browser or tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921941/close-kills-the-seesion-when-close-the-browser-or-tab)

Is there a solution for cross browser event. I need to check if user closes their window and to throw an ajax request to my database to sign them out.

I've looked everyone but most cases its not working in all browsers. Anyone have a solution? Or Alternative on how to do this perhaps a conditional statement depending on the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: @OP: As David said, this is a duplicate. The best answer (in the other question) is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921941/close-kills-the-seesion-when-close-the-browser-or-tab/1986131#1986131

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a thing exists. You can try an onunload, but that also fires when you refresh the page. This question has been the bane of many that want to do what you're asking for.