# Invalidate login in Laravel when user leaves the page

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

It seems a small and easy to solve problem, but I cant find any solution for it.

I want to login the users only for that session while the are browsing the site. As soon as they close the tab I want to make their session expired. As much as I know I can't do this in the built-in `Auth` class.

How could I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer: YOU CAN'T**

The session can be destroyed when the **entire** browser is closed by simply setting `expire_on_close` in `config/session.php` (also make sure you clear the cookies in your browser for this to work):

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

But there is no way to detect when **only** a tab is closed in the browser. The closest thing you would have is the JavasSript method [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) that triggers when you close a tab. But it also triggers when you navigate away from a page or hit the back button, and there's no way to differentiate between those actions.

---

You could set a very short session time on the server, and "*ping*" the server from any open page, to let it know to keep the session still in use, which would mean it would very quickly expire when the tabs that have the app open are closed, but that's an extremely ugly solution.

Comment: How I destroy a LARAVEL session when the entire browser is closed? That would be enough for me.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the solution for that case.

Comment: Look at that! I ran through it but it looks I missed that option. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Bogdan i've tried with 'expire_on_close' => true but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP is server side code, it only knows the last time/page that was accessed.

See: [Destroy PHP session on page leaving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177364/destroy-php-session-on-page-leaving)