# Need destroy session after close browser tab not whole browser

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I need to destroy session after page closed in browser. i tried to unset      **$_session['value'];**
 but it can not working it destroy current page but i need destroy  after closed in browser

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: no it does not work  for me i need destroy session after page closed in browser not some minutes..

Comment: You could listen to the event `unload` and 
asynchronously call a php page which then destroys the session. But I think every professional php/js-developer will hate me for that idea...

Answer (score -1):

You can write this

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

This will destroy session when the browser is closed.

Comment: Is this work on page close in browser?

Comment: No this will destroy session when the browse is closed.

Comment: May be you can find the answer here     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177364/destroy-php-session-on-page-leaving. hopefully this might help you