# Clear PHP session on tab close?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to logout each time the user closes it's tab. I've saw all similar questions, but I still haven't found anything that works.

Here's what I've done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
            confirm("Do you really want to logout?") && $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/admin/account/logout"
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

I've tried without the `confirm`, but it still doesn't work. I'm absolutely sure that it can be done, since my bank's website has the same functionality.

**EDIT:**
Without the `confirm` it does fire the logout ajax, but even when I browse trough the pages. Which reminds me, that my bank's website uses something like AngularJS, which is not exactly a true link-browsing system, right? Maybe that's why it works there?

Comment: maybe this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177447/3172875) can help

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that the request is executed asyncronously and gets terminated with the closing of the window.
If you set the `async` paramenter to false the ajax request will get executed before the tab/window is closed.

Unfortunately this won't solve your problem since this event is fired every time you're about to leave the page. If you are just trying to hack a solution you can use the approach mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057659/5173095 - trigger a timeout on the server side and logout the user if he doesn't make another request after the timeout has passed.

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeunload` is fired every time you say your browser to unload current html. It's happens even if you click on a link. When you cosle a tab, you also close the enviroment where  that page's js was executed. I don't think it can be done natively.

Comment: Yes, I've just updated my question. I've added an explanation, that it fires the logout ajax, but even when I browse trough the pages...