# Kill Asp.Net session when the browser or tab is closed

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, webforms

I am using forms authentication with Asp.Net 4. At the moment when the users click on logout link, I clear the session and call `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` and this prevents the users from going back to the site without a logging in again.

Now I want to kill the session when the browser or tab is closed. I tried doing this by handling `onbeforeunload` event, but I ended up killing the session after clicking any internal links.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication cookies **are session only**, that means that delete by browser when the browser close. Maybe you do not close all browsers tabs, but if you close them all the authentication cookies are lost.

About closing a tab, you do not know if the user have other tab opens.

A possible solution maybe is a call every 10 seconds back to the server to keep this authentication active or not, and set the authentication to end up after 20 seconds. So if not any signal come back, the user have gone. This can be done using javascript. From the other hand this can not let the user logout after some minutes of inactivity, so you may need a combination of this logic with something else.

Comment: Using FormsAuthentication you can be logged in across browser sessions.  That's why there is a timeout value you can set in your web.config to say how long you want a person to be in active for.

Answer (score 2):

[You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921984/290343), but you can [come close to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1922007/290343).

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is when your user explicitly logs out to also call `Session.Abandon()` to remove that user's session. But like others have said there is no way of knowing if the tab/window just closes without doing a logout in this fashion. The session will just hang around on the server until it expires.

Answer (score 0):

I answered another question that had a problem with session being killed when the user edited the web.config on a live site.  They were tracking users still being logged in with Session variables (dangerous).  But came up with a solution (untested solution) that could help people here.

FormsAuthentication allows you to maintain a person being active and logged in indefinitely.  But if they become inactive for e.g. 20 mins they will be logged out which is nice.  But to have them logged out at the time the close their browser is not possible (wait for it...) as setting the timeout value to 0 would cause them to be constantly logged in then out again.

So solution : at the time you log a person in using FormsAuthentication you could also set a standard session variable cookie that will be deleted when they close their browser.  This cookie would have non-identifying non-account related information.  Just a simple "loggedIn:yes".

Now all your code would need to have on it's masterpage/materlayout is a high level call in the page cycle or constructor of the page cycle (or even a custom attribute) that would check both cookie and the user identity:

```
if(!HasLoginCookie() || !System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   // redirect user to log in page.
}
```

Basically if the cookie is removed when the browser is closed, you will redirect the user to the log in page.

Hopefully that helps (and works.  As I said untested).