# Call ajax to clear session after user has left page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, regex

I want to clear the php session array every time a user leaves my page, but my page has links with query strings.  I don't want to clear the session array, when a user clicks on a link with a query string.  I have tried the following javascript code but it does not work when the user leaves the page.

somepage.php

```
var url = new RegExp(/somepage.php\?sort=.*/);
if (url.test(document.location.href)){
    //do nothing
}
else {
    $(window).unload(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'clear_session.php'
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921941/close-kill-the-session-when-the-browser-or-tab-is-closed

Answer (score 0):

Calling a webserivce onunload is **very unrealiable**. Why not just unset the `PHPSESSID` cookie? This wont clean up the session on the server, but it will give the user a new empty session when he visits again.