# saving session on browser

Tags: php, session

Is there anyway to destroy session after closing tabs.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['access']) || $_SESSION['access'] != 'yes')
{
    include("FrontPage.php");
    exit();
}
```

I include this code in some of my application. However it only works when I closes the browser completely. Is this the feature of session or my errors ?

Comment: Set session expiry time..

Comment: Possible duplicates,

 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958769/destroy-session-when-broswer-tab-closed
 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276226/clearing-session-variables-when-a-tab-is-closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The session cookie is per-process not per window. So even if you
>   selected New Window you'd still get the same session id. This behavior
>   makes sense. You wouldn't want a user to re-sign in each time they
>   opened a new window while browsing your site.
>
> I'm not aware off hand of any real way around this.

Answered by [Paul Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76456/paul-alexander) at [Why Doesn't Closing A Tab Delete A Session Cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76456/paul-alexander)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use something in javascript like:

```
window.onunload
```

Maybe to call a script destroying the session with session_destroy()