# How to clear session on closing the browser tab?

Tags: php, session

Hi I'm trying to clear all the session variables when the user closes the tab,
I have tried the following

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

but it clears the session only when the user closer the entire browser,
I have tried searching frome some links but I have found that not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [destroy session when broswer tab closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958769/destroy-session-when-broswer-tab-closed)

Comment: but that has no accepted answer and is not the answer what I need

Comment: See this answer. May be it will help you . 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276226/clearing-session-variables-when-a-tab-is-closed#answer-18276579

Comment: what is purpose to remove session on tab close, you can also use other way instead to remove session on tab

Comment: @sivabalan I have tried that code too but that not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers only destroy session cookies when the entire browser process is exited. There is no reliable method to determine if/when a user has closed a tab. There is an `onbeforeunload` handler you can attach to, and hopefully manage to make an ajax call to the server to say the tab's closing, but it's not reliable.

And what if the user has two or more tables open on your site? If they close one tab, the other one would effectively be logged out, even though the user fully intended to keep on using your site.

by : [Marc b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10958806/3164682)