# How to know browser is opened or not?

Tags: asp.net

I am doing an asp.net project.
In this i blocked user log in, meant's if a user logged in one system or browser he can't log in in other browser or system.

Now the problem is i want to free resources if the user directly closing the browser of shutdown the system.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is somewhat vague on 'how you block the user'. Nevertheless:
Http is a stateless protocoll and you are not able to tell if a browser window is open or not.

You can manipulate this behaviour be setting the session timeout lower. You can set a session cookie, which expires at the end of the session.

Alternativly there is a javascript snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921941/close-kill-the-session-when-the-browser-or-tab-is-closed), that imitates this behaviour. Scroll down a little bit to get the snippet.