# Session fixation issue for Multi-page Web application

Tags: asp.net, session-fixation

Our Web application has multiple pages and doesn't have any logout functionality.We have tried onunload method but it's not working in Chrome browser. We tried onbeforeunload method, but it's getting called for page redirection as well. Is there a way to end the session when the user closes the tab for multi-page web applications?

Answer (score 0):

For particular tab it is not possible, but if entire browser is closed then session can be destroyed.

For browser close you can put below code into your web.config :

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

You can try out ways given in this link: [Close/kill the session when the browser or tab is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921941/close-kill-the-session-when-the-browser-or-tab-is-closed)

Comment: We have the same configuration in Web.Config file and timeout is 60mins. <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60">
    </sessionState>

Comment: Check if there are updates in Chrome Browser. If yes, then update it and then check.